# why git doesn't merge with modified files when pulling

Tags: git

let's suppose I edited the file "test.html". It is not in staging areas. I want to pull, but in HEAD this file is modified too. Git won't let me pull because it would "overwrite existing changes". I so have to make a stash to put my modifications on side, pull and get back my stash. 
my question is, why doesn't git merge test.html (supposely we didn't modify the same line and there is no conflict) ?

I wouldn't like to overwrite my current test.html, but merge it with HEAD without commit it

Comment: Not really, I wouldn't  like to overwrite my file, I would like to merge it (like if I had commit it, except I would not lie to commit it, supposely because id'ont have my feature finished)

Comment: You generally shouldn't be pulling if your working directory or stage are dirty.  Think of a commit as the currency between your local setup and the remote.  You should generally deal in commits, and if you are in between them, then try to not to involve the remote.

Comment: search for, configure and experiment with 'autostash' -- might suit your desired workflow.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i will look at autostash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you `git pull` is that one or more new commits are coming into your local branch, moving the HEAD of that branch forward.  Your current working directory, to Git, can conceptually be thought of as a series of changes against the previous HEAD, before the pull happened.  If the changes brought in by the pull would render the diff for `test.html` substantially different such that Git cannot easily figure out how to express it in terms of the *new* HEAD, then you would tend to get the error which you are seeing.

As far as I know, you might also have *not* gotten this error, if, for example, the area of `test.html` which you modified was not altered at all by the changes coming in from the pull.

It is generally good Git etiquette to not do a `git pull` when your working directly or stage are dirty.  Rather, plan on pushing or pulling when they are both clean, you have made your commits, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thnks I get the logic. But in my case, wherever I modified the test.html (as an example, i make a comment at the end of the file, and in the remote another comment is at the beginnin), I still have the "would be overwritten by merge" error

Comment: It depends on whether Git's auto merge algorithm can cope with it.  But in any case, you can't really rely on it, because as you're seeing, it _might_ work or it might not.  Instead, just commit your local work first, do a `git stash`, or maybe throw it away, if you don't need it/aren't happy with it.

Comment: It's what I don't understand, I merge when I ave committed test.html, Git can merge it without problem, but it can't merge if my file is not committed like all file was in conflict

Comment: `Git can merge without problem`.  Not true at all.  You can get merge conflicts when doing a `git merge`, even if you working directory and stage are clean.  That your pull failed as it did implies that `test.html` would have been brought into conflict by that pull.

Comment: That's not what is happening : my file is edited, i try to pull and i get "local whanges would be overwritten by merge". Then i commit my file, without modify it, I launch fit pull and the file is merged. Did I miss something ?

Comment: You should review a good Git tutorial at this point.  There isn't anything else I can explain here to your original question.  As I mentioned, a `git pull` may or may not complete automatically, but in any case, you can't really rely on it being automatic.

Comment: sorry miss copy paste : I get "local whanges would be overwritten by merge"